# how to format c code in vscode with gnu format style?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, gnu

I work on a c project that default coding style is [GNU format style](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Formatting), I want to format it automatically, so do you have any suggestions?